# get data from table with two different constraint

Tags: mysql, wordpress

While working on a project for designing rest api I have to write queries which uses database of wordpress. What I've to do is get the post title and post featured images from posts table of wordpress, the problem is that wordpress stores data related to posts in two table wp_posts and wp_postmeta where wp_posts contains post related data like post title, post date, images url and many with different version of same data with revision for update data while postmeta table contain data related to attachment, meta decription etc. 
What I have to do is to get post_tile and post_featured_image url in same query call but id for featured image row in post is obtained from postmeta query and post_title is present in another row. How to make such query?

ex posts table

```
ID    date    title    content    parent       guid       status   type
1     11       ABC      hello       0        url-publish  publish  post
2     11       ABC    hello_world   1        url-revision revision revision
3     11       def                  1        fea_img_url  inherit  attachment
```

ex post meta table

```
meta_id    post_id     meta_key   meta_value
  1          1         edited         2
  2          1       featured_img_    3
```

meta_key 'featured image' define featured image with id value of key value using this key value I have to get featured image from posts table.

Comment: You need to give more information than this.  At least include the table schema.  Only a WordPress person would follow this.

Comment: Well. wordpress already have REST API. Why not use that?

Comment: @Rakib rest api only returned featured media id like in my example it will return 3

Comment: so you wanted the featured media URL?